# is there any particular software available so that i can practice the unix on my windows PC also

Tags: unix

actually my most of the work is on the windows only so it really not possible for me switch my unix operating system everytime. Can anyone help me with a software so that i can practice my unix on the windows.

Comment: You could use Cygwin, but Ubuntu (and others) provides bootable operating system that would be suffisant for testing.

Comment: Maybe some sort of virtualization software like Vmware or Virtualbox ?

Comment: i dont want to put any opinion for any software . all i want is to learn unix with the resources available to me. i want to learn i will do it by hook or crook.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cygwin.com/ lets you use linux console in windows. Or use some vitualization software.

Comment: it is asking for the package which package i need to install